# Eclipse neon resolve target definition is very slow

Tags: target-platform, eclipse-neon

Last week I installed Eclipse Neon. I started with a new workspace, because I didn't like any trouble with old stuff.
In our projects we have our own target definition, which looks like

[image]

You will notice, that we are relying on p2 directory instead of software sides. And we do have 15 of them. Not that many I think. But every time we change a existing directory it takes very long > 3-4-5 minutes to resolve the target definition.

[image]

What I do see, is that at 45% progress a second progress bar appears going through a lot of different http sites. But why? We are using p2 directories not software sides. Does anybody know what is happening and if there are any settings I have to set? Because I am sure that everything what is necessary is available within the target definitions.